# How to make attached image using Custom Painter in flutter

Tags: flutter, custom-painter

I'm trying to make custom shape same as attached image. How can i make this custom shape using custom Painter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [plogon_clipper](https://pub.dev/packages/polygon_clipper) to make this design

```
import 'package:polygon_clipper/polygon_clipper.dart';  // Import package for ClipPolygon

ClipPolygon(  
 sides: 6, 
 borderRadius: 10, 
 rotate: 90.0,
 boxShadows: [  
  PolygonBoxShadow(color: Colors.black, elevation: 1.0),
  PolygonBoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, elevation: 5.0)
 ],
 child: Container(color: Colors.black),
);
```